# Eclipse: Android not adding id class to R.java

Tags: android

I am currently writing a program for an android app and I keep running into a problem where I get an error `"id cannot be resolved or is not a field"`. For example I have a line of code:

```
mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);
```

After viewing the `R.java` class there is no id class. I previously copied and pasted an example online and it also implemented a line of code that was similar and it added the id class to `R.java`.

I'm just wondering how to correct this problem. I have researched it and some people suggested to others to `import android.R` and this corrects some errors but then creates new ones saying that the part after is not in that category.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error/3259974#3259974

Comment: Project > Clean.  And then do a refresh on your project.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes cleaning the project resolves problems like this.  (Select clean from the project menu.)

Answer (score 3):

Clean clean clean. Also saving and restarting helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Eclipse development environment, try just deleting the R.java file and re running the project. I ran into a couple of issues where Eclipse wouldn't update the file right away and I had to delete it to get Eclipse to regenerate it (with the updated values).

Comment: How do I get it to regenerate it? I tried running it, and changing the settings to build automatically and it won't regenerate it.

Comment: are there any errors in your project? Try selecting the project and press F5 or right clicking on the project and selecting Refresh.